# Android Failed allocating 223605 bytes for text/blob at 4,2 error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I can't understand what the error means ?.. i store large data into the database dynamically.i store five raw and delete first raw after add latest sixth. my code is working fine in Nexus 7.0 and other device but the error show in small device or law storage device.

**Error**

```
 01-24 11:04:35.927: E/CursorWindow(30681): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 340236, freeSpace() = 225346, numRows = 5
 01-24 11:04:35.927: E/CursorWindow(30681): not growing since there are already 5 row(s), max size 1048576
 01-24 11:04:35.927: E/Cursor(30681): Failed allocating 340236 bytes for text/blob at 4,2
```

**Class**

```
           //this is for reading the raw data from the database - updated

databse = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor  cursor = databse.rawQuery("select * from comments where newspaper = " + newspaper,null);
            String quantity_tb = null ;
            try 
            {                   
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    String name_tb = cursor.getString(0);
                    String price_tb = cursor.getString(1);
                    quantity_tb = cursor.getString(2);
                         }

            }
            finally
            {
                 if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
                        cursor.close();
                    } 

                databse.close();
            }       
   ////////////

            databse = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= databse.rawQuery("Select count(*) from comments;", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int countdb= cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        databse.close();


        if (countdb == 5) 
        {   
            deletefirstraw();
        }

        if (!masterData.isEmpty()) {

            databse = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(helper.NEWSPAPER_NAME,masterData.get(0).newspaper);//name
            cv.put(helper.NEWSPAPER_NEWS,json);// large data
            databse.insert(helper.NEWSPAPER, null, cv);
            databse.close();
        }
    }
}

public void deletefirstraw() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          databse = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor1 = databse.query(helper.NEWSPAPER, null, null, null, null, null, null); 
                if(cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
                    String rowId = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(helper.COLUMN_ID)); 

                    databse.delete(helper.NEWSPAPER, helper.COLUMN_ID + "=?",  new String[]{rowId});
                   }
          cursor1.close();
        databse.close();

}
```

Comment: without your code we can only guess that it is due to lack of memory

Comment: i added my code which shown how i stored and delete the first raw.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there wil be quite a performance penalty with you kepp on opening and closing your DB.  Keep a reference to it for **one** set of operations.

Secondly, when closing the DB, put this into a `finally` block to ensure that it is called.

Thirdly, if the `if (!masterData.isEmpty()) {` block is not entered then the DB is not closed.

Also can you post more of your stacktrace, so we can see where the error is happening.